# How can I print the first three characters of a column in descending order?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am a bit new to MySQL and I'm facing a bit of difficulty executing a query to meet the following requirements:

Write a query to display the first 3 characters of all customer names in descending order. Name the column `CUSTOMER_NAME` (use the string method).

The query I wrote is:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CustomerName 1,3)  as CUSTOMER_NAME from customer  order by desc ;
```

The table where I have all my customer information is called `customer`. Currently, whenever I execute this query I get a syntax error.

Comment: Your `SUBSTRING` clause needs a comma between `CustomerName` and `1`. Furthermore, your `ORDER BY` clause needs to name a column that the query should order by. In this case, that would be `CUSTOMER_NAME`.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a Missing Comma in the `SUBSTRING(CustomerName 1,3)` -- should be `SUBSTRING(CustomerName, 1,3)` instead, and the `order by desc` misses a column name.

The following sequence would apparently run w/o Errors in MySql 8

```
Create Table customer (CustomerName Char(30));
Insert Into customer (CustomerName) Values ('Smith');

SELECT SUBSTRING(CustomerName, 1,3)  as CUSTOMER_NAME 
from customer  order by CustomerName desc ;
```

See also https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3dba69a4a83eb06cf50156dfd333fead